# How can I point all references to an object to a different object?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have object `a`.  Object `a` has several references pointing to it, but I don't know what these are.  I plan to destroy object `a`, but first I want to point all of its references to a new object `b`.

One way (if possible) would be if I could determine all of the references to object `a`, I could explicitly re-assign them to `b`.  However, I have not found a way to determine an objects references.

Or is there some other solution altogether for accomplishing this?

EDIT:

Here is the scenario:

In Firefox, I have an element in the DOM (tabbrowser tab) that will get removed from the DOM and another one put in its place, that will hold the data necessary to restore the tab to the state of the original tab when the tab is restored (this is a common method of "unloading" a tab).  However, other objects have a reference to the tab, and simply removing the tab from the DOM breaks these references, sometimes also breaking functionality of code in other places.  I would like to point all of the references of the old tab to the new one.

EDIT 2:

Firefox has native methods `addTab` and `removeTab`.  I am using both methods, `removeTab` to remove a tab, which will remove it from the DOM (among other things without attempting to give an in-depth tutorial on Firefox's tabbrowser-tab model), then I will use `addTab` method to put a new tab in its place, which will create a new tab element and add it to the DOM.  This is a completely new object, and thus I want the references that were pointing to the old tab to now point to the new tab.

I don't know if simply assigning a=b in this case would work, as tabbrowser-tabs are quite complex.

Comment: Could you provide some sample of the object `a` ?

Comment: Read about XY problem.

Comment: You want all references pointing `a` to now point `b`?

Comment: By "XY problem", Amit means that we think you're asking us to solve X so that you can do Y.  It usually turns out that there's a much better way to do Y, so if you could explain why you want to do what you want to do, it would be better for all involved.

Comment: if you are within closure of all affected vars, you can literally just say `a=b;` and any function using the name `a` will see what was called `b` upon the next execution.

Comment: `a = b` will accomplish both of those things, anything that was pointing at a will now point at b, and the object originally bound to a will be garbage-collected.

Comment: @JaredSmith: but only if you call `a=b` within the closure of all affected vars; if something has already duped `a`, laundered its name by passing it as an argument to a function, or used it in a `.bind()`, it won't see the new values...

Comment: @dandavis correct, it would have to be reassigned in the original scope. None of this explains though how the OP expects to 'destroy' a javascript object, and the answer to that is likely going to be telling about what's really going on here.

Comment: i should mention that qualifying the var name up to a common scope would be sufficient for breaking through closure; ex: use `window.a` instead of just `a`, and then you can change `window.a` at any time (ala `window.a={a:2}`), and anything using `window.a` will get the new stuff, despite closure/binding/etc... it doesn't have to be global like `window`, it just needs to be above (seen by all) function consumers.

Comment: If you mean that you have a reference to another window you opened via `window.open()` then my solution (with the caveat mentioned by dandavis) should work fine, although you'll want to profile for memory leaks from unremoved event handlers. Note that you will be unable to programmatically close the window whose reference you're replacing. Nor would I refer to any of this as 'common', mind telling us what you're actually trying to do here (especially since we've asked multiple times)?

Comment: @JaredSmith - wow, I thought I had done that - I just could have left out the parenthetical "common" comment.  But I will try again...

Comment: @Allasso the question is *why*? Why are you programmatically opening a window, keeping a ref, then trying to swap it out for another one? What's your endgame? Your revision was helpful but still very narrowly focused without telling us what effect you are hoping to achieve with all of these programmatic gymnastics.

Comment: Ah ok. That only works for firefox for android plugins (according to MDN). You need to edit your question (especially adding the right tags) so that its clear what you are asking. Since you made no mention of firefox, android, or that it was a plugin, we just assumed it was a general javascript question, and it isn't at all. That missing context is the source of the confusion. Unfortunately I know absolutely nothing about writing firefox plugins. Please edit your question.

Comment: @JaredSmith: FWIW, I am not opening a new window - I don't know what I said to give that impression - I am opening a new tab within the same window.  As I said before, this is a common method used of "unloading" tabs in Firefox.  But to attempt to try to explain what unloading a tab is and why this method works would require a tutorial on Firefox's model of a tabbrowser-tab, Firefox's implementation of session restore, would be extremely lengthy, and I believe out of the scope of simply asking a Javascript question on Stack Overflow.  I believe the point of my question is plain.

Comment: @JaredSmith "we just assumed it was a general javascript question, and it isn't at all" - actually, it *was* a general javascript question, that is how I meant it.  Some wanted me to expound to see if there was other things to explore (referring to the "XY" question thing), but the original question was exactly how I meant it, and I was indeed looking for information pertaining to javascript objects generally.

Comment: The answer I gave you is sufficient for js objects in general. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104344/discussion-between-allasso-and-jared-smith).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do some kind of manual tracking, there is no way to determine what references are held to an object.

The `DOM`, for example, sets all sorts of pointers to various objects when you insert an element...

Such as

- `<element>.parentNode`
- `<element>.firstChild`
- `<element>.nextSiblingNode`

and many others.

When you remove an object from the DOM, those references are all manually updated, though behind the scenes.